# Is it possible to retrieve a single snapshot from a network camera using ONVIF?

Tags: onvif

I am trying to retrieve single snapshots (not video streaming) using ONVIF. Is this even possible? If so, how?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to user the GetSnapshotUri function from the [Media Service specs](http://www.onvif.org/specs/srv/media/ONVIF-Media-Service-Spec-v242.pdf).

From the specs:

> **5.16.1  Request snapshot URI**
>
> A Network client uses the GetSnapshotUri command to obtain a JPEG snhapshot from the device. The returned URI
>   shall remain valid indefinitely even if the profile is changed. The
>   ValidUntilConnect, ValidUntilReboot and Timeout Parameter shall be set
>   accordingly (ValidUntilConnect=false, ValidUntilReboot=false,
>   timeout=PT0S). The URI can be used for acquiring a JPEG image through
>   a HTTP GET operation.
>
> The image encoding will always be JPEG
>   regardless of the encoding setting in the media profile. The JPEG
>   settings (like resolution or quality) should be taken from the profile
>   if suitable. The provided image shall be updated automatically and
>   independent from calls to GetSnapshotUri.